# Controlling output of extra elements from paginate_links() in WordPreess

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, pagination

[image: Spaces in red are the area i need to get rid of.]

The image above displays the "Extra" information that im trying to get rid of surrounded in red with the results from the paginate _links() function. I would like it to only ever show the current page number with two on either side along with previous and next buttons. I would like to remove the showing of the last page and first page links as well as the ellipsis before them. My Current code doing the output is below.

```
    global $wp_query;

if ($total_pages > 1) {
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    $links = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => '<',
        'next_text' => '>',
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'type'  => 'array'
    ));
    foreach($links as $link){

    }
    echo $links;
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated ive completely dissected the documentation on this function and cannot figure it out.

Comment: i have an error in my code because i dont have echo $link in the foreach. this is my mistake please disregard

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here and looks at this at a later date, Here is how i solved it. Probably not the best way to do it but it achieves the desired result.

i hid the dots through CSS and then to get rid of the first and last page links i called an unset on where i knew they would always be only when it needed to be removed.

```
global $wp_query;

if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) {
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    $links = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => '<',
        'next_text' => '>',
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'type' => 'array'
    ));
    if($current_page > 3){
        unset($links[1]);
    }
    if($current_page <= $wp_query->max_num_pages - 3){
        unset($links[count($links) - 1]);
    }
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        echo $link;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a way to hide dots not using CSS : 
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (strpos($link, 'dots') === false)
        echo '<li>' . $link . '</li>';
}
It's better, because if you use <ul> <li> structure, you need to hide the <li> completely, not just the <a> tag inside the <li>.